# Oracle query optimization while inserting million records

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, query-optimization, oracle12c

We are trying to execute a query in our production environment, which is taking unexpectedly more than 5 hours and still not getting completed. This query is expected to insert 1.8 million records.I have full control on the FSG_WRK.FSG_PRCB_CSP_EXT_HR table but FAC.CMC_PRSQ_SITE_QA is our system table and I can't add any index on it.

Please suggest.

**Query :**

```
INSERT INTO FAC.CMC_PRSQ_SITE_QA 
WITH CTE (MPIN, TAX_ID_NBR, POS_ADR_ID, BSAR_ID, CANC_DT, EFF_DT, EXTND_HRS)
AS(
    SELECT EXT.MPIN , 
    EXT.TAX_ID_NBR  , 
    EXT.POS_ADR_ID  , 
    EXT.BSAR_ID     , 
    temp.CANC_DT    , 
    EXT.EFF_DT      ,   
    EXT.EXTND_HRS 
    FROM FSG_WRK.FSG_PRCB_CSP_EXT_HR ext
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT  EXT.MPIN, 
                    EXT.TAX_ID_NBR, 
                    EXT.POS_ADR_ID, 
                    EXT.BSAR_ID, 
                    MAX(EXT.CANC_DT) CANC_DT
                FROM FSG_WRK.FSG_PRCB_CSP_EXT_HR EXT
                WHERE FLAG ='Y'
                GROUP BY EXT.MPIN, EXT.TAX_ID_NBR, EXT.POS_ADR_ID, EXT.BSAR_ID) temp
    ON( ext.MPIN = temp.MPIN
    AND ext.TAX_ID_NBR = temp.TAX_ID_NBR
    AND ext.POS_ADR_ID = temp.POS_ADR_ID
    AND ext.BSAR_ID    = temp.BSAR_ID
    AND ext.CANC_DT    = temp.CANC_DT)
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
        PRSQ.PRPR_ID,
        PRSQ.PRAD_ID ,
        PRSQ.PRAD_TYPE,
        PRSQ.PRAD_EFF_DT,
        EXT.EFF_DT  PRSQ_LAST_VER_DT,
        CASE    WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='W' THEN 'EHRW'
                WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='B' THEN 'EHRB'
                WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='E' THEN 'EHRE'
                WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='N' THEN 'EHRN'
        END AS PRSQ_MCTR_ITEM,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_INIT_VER_DT,
        EXT.CANC_DT PRSQ_NEXT_VER_DT,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_RCVD_VER_DT,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_VSRC,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_PRIM_VER_IND,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_VRSL,
        ' ' PRSQ_LAST_VER_NAME,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_VMTH,
        ' ' PRSQ_COMMENT,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_LOCK_TOKEN,
        PRSQ.ATXR_SOURCE_ID         
        FROM FAC.CMC_PRSQ_SITE_QA PRSQ 
        JOIN CTE EXT
        ON EXT.MPIN = SUBSTR(PRSQ.PRPR_ID,1,9)
        AND TRIM(EXT.BSAR_ID) = TRIM (PRSQ.PRSQ_LAST_VER_NAME)
        AND TRIM (EXT.POS_ADR_ID) = TRIM (PRSQ.PRSQ_COMMENT)
        AND TRIM(EXT.CANC_DT) = TRIM(PRSQ.PRSQ_NEXT_VER_DT)
        AND PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_ITEM IN ('SAID')
        AND NOT EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1 FROM FAC.CMC_NWPR_RELATION NWPR
                        WHERE NWPR.PRPR_ID = PRSQ.PRPR_ID    
                        AND NWPR.NWNW_ID = 'MINETWORK'
            );
```

**`Explain plan :`**

[image]

Comment: Could you enable sql trace and post it here? We need exact wait events during this insert. Last elapsed time is too big in the line "load table conventional". Probably there were table or row locks

Comment: I don't want to guess, so it would be better to get real wait events. If you have EE with licensed diagnostic and tuning packs, it would be easier to provide ashrpt output or raw ash dump

Answer (score 0):

If you 'just' migrate data from A to B you may have a look if a `merge into` and a `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  INSERT` at the end of the statement wouldn't be the better choice here.

1.8 million records shouldn't challenge your oracle instance too much with that.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, looks like you want to get latest rows by EXT.CANC_DT in each group. If that is the case, it would be easier to use [FIRST/LAST aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238):

```sql
INSERT INTO FAC.CMC_PRSQ_SITE_QA 
WITH CTE (MPIN, TAX_ID_NBR, POS_ADR_ID, BSAR_ID, CANC_DT, EFF_DT, EXTND_HRS)
AS(
    SELECT
            EXT.MPIN, EXT.TAX_ID_NBR, EXT.POS_ADR_ID, EXT.BSAR_ID
           ,MAX(EXT.CANC_DT) CANC_DT
           ,MAX(EXT.EFF_DT   ) keep(dense_rank first order by EXT.CANC_DT desc) EFF_DT
           ,MAX(EXT.EXTND_HRS) keep(dense_rank first order by EXT.CANC_DT desc) EXTND_HRS
    FROM FSG_WRK.FSG_PRCB_CSP_EXT_HR EXT
    WHERE FLAG ='Y'
    GROUP BY EXT.MPIN, EXT.TAX_ID_NBR, EXT.POS_ADR_ID, EXT.BSAR_ID
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
        PRSQ.PRPR_ID,
        PRSQ.PRAD_ID ,
        PRSQ.PRAD_TYPE,
        PRSQ.PRAD_EFF_DT,
        EXT.EFF_DT  PRSQ_LAST_VER_DT,
        CASE    WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='W' THEN 'EHRW'
                WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='B' THEN 'EHRB'
                WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='E' THEN 'EHRE'
                WHEN TRIM(EXT.EXTND_HRS)='N' THEN 'EHRN'
        END AS PRSQ_MCTR_ITEM,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_INIT_VER_DT,
        EXT.CANC_DT PRSQ_NEXT_VER_DT,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_RCVD_VER_DT,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_VSRC,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_PRIM_VER_IND,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_VRSL,
        ' ' PRSQ_LAST_VER_NAME,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_VMTH,
        ' ' PRSQ_COMMENT,
        PRSQ.PRSQ_LOCK_TOKEN,
        PRSQ.ATXR_SOURCE_ID         
        FROM FAC.CMC_PRSQ_SITE_QA PRSQ 
        JOIN CTE EXT
        ON EXT.MPIN = SUBSTR(PRSQ.PRPR_ID,1,9)
        AND TRIM(EXT.BSAR_ID) = TRIM (PRSQ.PRSQ_LAST_VER_NAME)
        AND TRIM (EXT.POS_ADR_ID) = TRIM (PRSQ.PRSQ_COMMENT)
        AND TRIM(EXT.CANC_DT) = TRIM(PRSQ.PRSQ_NEXT_VER_DT)
        AND PRSQ.PRSQ_MCTR_ITEM IN ('SAID')
        AND NOT EXISTS(
                        SELECT 1 FROM FAC.CMC_NWPR_RELATION NWPR
                        WHERE NWPR.PRPR_ID = PRSQ.PRPR_ID    
                        AND NWPR.NWNW_ID = 'MINETWORK'
            );
```